# Difference between AAD authentication libraries and WebAuthenticationCoreManager

Tags: adal

It appears that if you are writing an Win10 UWP app, you can get AAD tokens by using the WebAuthenticationCoreManager class or by using the MSAL libraries. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?  It seems like the MSAL libraries have been more recently updated (to support AAD v2.0 endpoint, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

MSAL is cross-platform and can get a token from Azure AD v2.0 or Azure AD B2C . If you want to get an access token and call the Microsoft Graph using OAuth 2.0 against the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint for a UWP application , you'd use MSAL library and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/is-is/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2/) is a code sample .

Comment: Thanks for the sample link.  Is there a reason to choose MSAL over the WebAuthenticationCoreManager built into Windows? Why are there two ways to ostensibly do the same thing? Are they not actually the same?

Comment: In Windows 10’s Universal Windows Platform , i suggest using WebAccountManager/WebAuthenticationCoreManager  which  take advantage of the user tokens stored in the system . [Reference document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/08/03/develop-windows-universal-apps-with-azure-ad-and-the-windows-10-identity-api/).

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what that really means. Does it mean that users will see more credential prompts if I use MSAL since it can't use tokens stored in the system? Does the WebAccountManager library offer all the features that MSAL offers?

Comment: MSAL/ADAL will  keep tokens in its own cache, instead of leveraging the Windows10 system accounts as WebAccountManager . But they both works with azure ad account login .

Comment: So if I am writing an app that is only a Win10 UWP app, is there any reason not to use WebAccountManager? There's no reason to prefer MSAL if the app is not going to be cross platform?

Comment: yes, if using only Win10 UWP app ,WebAccountManager is the better choice . But if you want your apps to have their own identity(client credential flow), without user involvement, or for use of raw credentials , you should use ADAL/MSAL .